# Depending on whether to say "vraiment pas" or "pas vraiment", does the meaning of this sentence change?

Tags: sens, négation, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

> Cette idée ne les a vraiment pas emballés.

vs

> Cette idée ne les a pas vraiment emballés.

I wonder if the difference in meaning between "**really not**" and "**not really**" in English applies to French as well.

Comment: La première version insiste sur le *pas*, elle rejette l'idée, la seconde qui indique que l'idée n'est pas acceptée, mais qu'elle n'est pas obligatoirement rejetée.

Comment: "vraiment pas" is strong, and "pas vraiment" is soft :)

Comment: Yes. On a sidenote, there is a case "really" doesn't translate as "vraiment", and it's when it means "actually" : "*I thought he was ... but he was really ...". In that case you say "en fait" (casual), or "en réalité" (a little more formal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. “Pas vraiment” means that the statement is more false than true, it can mean “to a small extent” or it can be a weak “not” (literally, it refutes “vraiment” which would be an intensifier). “Vraiment pas” insists on the negation. The distinction is the same as in English: “pas vraiment” = “not really”, “vraiment pas” = “really not”.

Answer (score 0):

@Gilles has the answer nailed, but I think the **reasoning behind it** bears mentioning.  In this case:

> Cette idée ne les a vraiment pas emballés.

the word `vraiment` is acting as an adverb to the word `pas`.  Therefore, graphically, it would have to be represented as:

```
( vraiment -> pas ) -> emballés
```

vs

> Cette idée ne les a pas vraiment emballés.

where `vraiment` is acting as a defining adverb of `emballés`.  Therefore, the graphic representation of that would be:

```
vraiment -> ( pas -> emballés )
```