# "pas vraiment" and "pas trop": Which is greater in degree?

Tags: sens

Practically, I suppose that people don’t pay much attention to which of them to use in daily conversation, but strictly speaking, which is considered to be "***more*** my cup of tea"?

> - C'est pas vraiment ma tasse de thé.
> - C'est pas trop ma tasse de thé.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ce n'est pas ma tasse de thé* is still used in France although essentially by educated/upper class people and very rarely otherwise, especially by younger generations who might not even know its meaning.

About the degree, I would say *ce n'est pas trop ma tasse de thé* is slightly lighter than *ce n'est pas vraiment ma tasse de thé* as the former doesn't rule out it might be a little *ma tasse de thé* while the latter politely states that the truth is it is not *ma tasse de thé*. Not everyone agrees though, as shows @Quidam's comment and downvote.

An even stronger expression which goes straight to the point would be *ce n'est vraiment pas ma tasse de thé*. See [Depending on whether to say "vraiment pas" or "pas vraiment", does the meaning of this sentence change?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17843/depending-on-whether-to-say-vraiment-pas-or-pas-vraiment-does-the-meaning-o)

Comment: pas trop mon x est moins formel que pas vraiment mon x, en tant que langage parlé.....ignore its meaning: not know its meaning you mean. Ignorer is a false friend when meaning  to not know something.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de "bonne réponse". C'est une opinion personnelle, d'autres personnes diront que "pas trop" est plus fort que "pas vraiment". On peut vraiment considérer comme équivalentes ces 2 expressions, ça rentre dans le "chipotage" et les opinons personnelles fondés uniquement sur des ressentis, et sur aucune règle.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je n'ai jamais affirmé que mon opinion sur la différence de degré entre *pas trop* et *pas vraiment* était autre chose qu'une opinion. *I would say* indique clairement que je ne donne pas une règle indiscutable. J'ai aussi indiqué pourquoi j'avais cette opinion et que s'il fallait clairement indiquer son désaccord, *vraiment pas* était la bonne combinaison d'adverbes.

Comment: Oui tout à fait, c'est une question de ressenti. Il n'y a qu'avec "Vraiment pas" qu'il y ait une réelle différence de degré, bien perceptible.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, we wouldn't *usually* say `ma tasse de thé` in French; usually we would say,

> - C'est pas vraiment mon truc.
> - C'est pas trop mon truc.

The nuance (at least in my area!) between the two sentences is not one of degree: they both mean the same thing as far as strength or emphasis is concerned.  The nuance lies more in context.

I would *tend* to use `vraiment` in a case where someone expected it to be my cup of tea, whereas I would *tend* to use `trop` in a situation where I am in a discussion setting where there isn't really any expectation as to what my cup of tea is.

In other words, if my boss is asking me to do something that I really don't know how to do, I would tend more to use `vraiment`, whereas if I'm talking with a friend about a particular activity, I might interject the latter expression.

## Bottom line:

They're synonymous.  You can use them interchangeably.  There is a slight nuance, however, as I outlined above.

Comment: Actually, I would generally expect a plain "C'est pas mon truc". We like to keep it short.

Comment: @Matthieu, that's true, we frequently would.  My point was to distinguish between the two options given.

Comment: I'd add that C'est pas vraiment mon truc is formal, while «C'est pas trop mon truc» is familiar mostly, you wouldn't say it to your boss for instance.

Comment: @Yann, lol, in Quebec, trop goes with your boss too.  :)

Comment: @anonymous2 ahah you are right ;-), but in that context «c'est pas trop mon truc» I feel like it's no as clean as «C'est pas vraiment mon truc»

Comment: I'm upvoting your comment because from my reading, it appears that in Europe, you are right about that.  In Quebec (at least my region), honestly, I couldn't have told a difference.

Comment: @YannChabot "mon truc" is anything but formal. In a formal context, something like "Ce n'est pas ce que je préfère" would be way better, or even "Ce n'est pas ma tasse de thé", but just don't say "C'est pas [vraiment] mon truc" to your boss, which could be interpreted as rude, depending on the company.

Comment: @Rightleg I know obviously, but «Ma tasse de thé» can be formaly used, I was mostly talking about «Ce n'est pas trop» versus «Ce n'est pas vraiment». In my opinion, Ce n'est pas trop would be something we'd be saying between friends but the «Vraiment» word fits better in this case.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Pas ma tasse de thé est utilisé en France. Bien sûr que si, c'est une expression française. Personnellement je l'utilise quelque fois (J'habite Paris), elle peut être trouvée à de multiples reprises si on la cherche sur google. Et elle a même son article dédié sur le très bon site expressio http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/ce-n-est-pas-ma-tasse-de-the.php

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE, thanks for your feedback!  Of course, I'm from a different region...  :)  And I did say, *usually*.  But that wasn't the point of the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, those are very similar expressions.
However, some may disagree, but to me "C'est pas trop..." is more colloquial, oral, than the first form. And in a proper written form, I would rather go with "Ce n'est pas vraiment ma tasse de thé", but in oral "C'est pas trop" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec ta réponse, la différence est plus dans le registre de langue que dans le degré, qui est une interprétation personnelle (aucune réponse n'est la bonne)

Answer (score 0):

Les 2 expressions sont quasiment identiques, une personne peut utiliser l'une ou l'autre de ces expressions pour dire la même chose. Il n'y a pas vraiment de gradation, cela revient au même.
Toutes les personnes qui diront qu'il y a une gradation, en trouveront une différente. Certaines personnes trouveront que "pas vraiment" et plus fort que "pas trop", d'autres le contraire.
Aucune source n'existe pour dire que "pas vraiment" est plus ou moins que "pas trop". C'est un peu du *chipotage*.

Ce qui intéressant de considérer: Est-ce que je peux utiliser l'une ou l'autre de ces expressions et dire la même chose. Sont-elles interchangeables?

Je pense que oui. Tout dépend **des habitudes** d'expression de la personne.
C'est une expression que les personnes auront souvent tendance à employer toute faite.
Par exemple, une personne qui dira "C'est pas vraiment ma tasse de thé", vous constaterez qu'*elle aura toujours tendance à la ressortir telle quelle*.

C'est *pas vraiment* ma tasse de thé.
C'est *pas trop* ma tasse de thé.

pas vraiment = pas trop.
Bien malin qui dira si "pas vraiment" est plus ou moins que "pas trop".
Et surtout, **il sera toujours obligé** de dire "à mon avis".
**Aucune réponse n'est la bonne.
C'et une question d'opinion.**

- Pour le dire plus fortement:
  C'est vraiment **pas** ma tasse de thé. (very strong).
  Là, il y a *clairement* une différence de nuance.