# French equivalent of "my cup of tea"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/my-cup-of-tea.html

One expression that I consider a "classic" English one is "my cup of tea".

Does the literal translation in French, i.e. "ma tasse de thé", sound enough idiomatic to native French speakers that are not necessarily familiar with the original English one?

What about also for the negation as in

> Hollywood blockbusters are not my cup of tea.
>
> Les blockbusters hollywoodiens ne sont pas ma tasse de thé.

Is the French sentence idiomatic? Or something like the following renders better the meaning in French?

> Les blockbusters hollywoodiens, c'est pas mon truc.

Comment: « Ce n'est pas ma tasse de thé » est très employé en France. Je suppose que pratiquement tout le monde le comprend. Je pourrais en écrire beaucoup sur le sujet mais je ne pourrais pas faire mieux que [ça](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-c/809-ce-nest-pas-ma-tasse-de-the.html) et [ça](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/ce-nest-pas-ma-tasse-de-the/), et le plagiat ce n'est pas vraiment ma tasse de thé.

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23456/1109

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks. "Ce n'est pas ma tasse de thé is still used in France although essentially by educated/upper class people and very rarely otherwise, especially by younger generations who might not even know its meaning." (Taken from the linked answer.) and "« Ce n'est pas ma tasse de thé » est très employé en France. Je suppose que pratiquement tout le monde le comprend."  (see Laure comment above) are a bit contradictory, aren't they?

Comment: @Laure Merci pour le commentaire et les liens. Veuille voir mon commentaire ci-dessus.

Comment: @Dimitris Ça peut aussi dépendre des milieux. Très employé ne veut pas dire qu'absolument tout le monde l'emploi. Seule une étude statistique pourrait en dire plus. Je n'ai pas pu m'empêcher de faire le commentaire pour faire le « jeu de mots » en contexte.

Comment: Not that contradictory, just slightly different experiences. There is nothing scientific in my reply which is just an opinion. To clarify: I definitely use and hear the expression around me, I noticed younger people tend to use it less while still understanding it but I also happened to meet even younger people that were clueless in front of it. I fully agree with Laure's *pratiquement tout le monde le comprend* which means under the line *il existe une très petite minorité de gens qui ne le comprend pas*.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I hear often the negative form "c'est pas ma tasse de thé" in France but almost never the affirmative "c'est ma tasse de thé" .

"C'est mon truc" works in both affirmative and negative forms.

The familiar "c'est (pas) mon délire" works as well in circles of young friends.

Another familiar expression is "c'est (pas) mon dada", which is older. It works in negative form but is mostly used affirmatively.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a positive sentence, expressing someone's affect for an idea, object or situation, the expression "**ça me botte !**" may suit you.

It comes from the word "Botte", French translation of the word boot. You feel comfortable in the boot, it suits you, it becomes your boot, not because you wear the boot, but because the boot "wears you" as it was designed for your foot.

It may be too close of the expression "Comme un gant" (like a glove), because of the idea of a physical fit but it can be relevant depending on the context.