# Quelles seraient d’autres manières plus élégantes d’exprimer l’idée citée dans le corps de la question?

Tags: formulation, reformulation

Je cherche d’autres façons plus élégantes d’exprimer l’idée suivante, des tournures d’un autre style et de meilleure langue. En gros, je souhaiterais qu’on me présente des versions/variantes enrichies qui se voudraient plus jolies et intéressantes, histoire d’améliorer mon style d’écriture.

Voici la phrase en question:

> La lenteur est encouragée par les hautes sphères et surtout par les sphères moyennes de la bureaucratie car elle appelle plus d’employés (subalternes ou subordonnés), ce qui/et implique plus de cadres¹. Ces derniers voient donc l’existence de leurs postes légitimée.

¹ Définition *cadre*: Personne qui a des fonctions de direction.

Comment: Parlant des tasses de thé : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/french-equivalent-of-my-cup-of-tea :-)!

Comment: Devrais-je plutôt écrire: ce ne sont pas ma tasse de thé, voire ce n’est pas ma tasse de thé?

Comment: Je ne sais pas vraiment:-)!

Comment: Hé là là! Attendons de voir ce qu’en pensent les sages!

Comment: Non locuteurs natif. Juste mon opinion : Clarté, concision, architecture et apparemment compréhension, ce ne sont pas mes tasses de thé.

Comment: Les films pornographiques ne sont pas ma tasse de thé, je préfère l’action. https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_être_la_tasse_de_thé

Comment: Très bien, merci !

Comment: Les maths, c’est sa tasse de thé. https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tasse_de_thé

Comment: J’imagine que toutes les variantes sont correctes et qu’au final ce n’est qu’une question de style, sans plus.

Comment: Bois ton thé Sémiramis.

Comment: Il n’y a pas de thé, évidemment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La lenteur est encouragée par les hautes sphères et surtout par les sphères moyennes de la bureaucratie car elle appelle plus d’employés (subalternes ou subordonnés), ce qui/et implique plus de cadres¹. Ces derniers voient donc l’existence de leurs postes légitimée.

Ajourner et temporiser sont des pratiques que  la bureaucratie encourage dans ses plus hautes sphères, mais pas seulement, ce qui a le but inavouable d'augmenter le personnel de bas étage, conséquence qui entraine automatiquement la légitimité d'un nombre accru de cadres.

P.S.      Pas de bonus svp, vote normal si accepté.